# Using PFLogInViewController with Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am getting a "use of undeclared type" error when trying to use `PFLogInViewController` and `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` in the default view controller of my Swift project. The code for my ViewController.swift file is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var logInViewController:PFLogInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        logInController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(logInController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I've already imported Parse in the bridging header and am able to send data to the Parse servers. For some reason the `PFLogInViewController` won't work though. Since Parse hasn't updated their tutorial for Swift, I was hoping someone could give me some insight into how to fix this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the parse SDK, you will see there are a couple of frameworks present. You need to use the ParseUI.framework. Just drag the framework into your frameworks folder in Xcode, and remember to check the 'copy items if needed' option. Then you should also include the framework in you swift file like so:

```
import ParseUI
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. This seems to be an issue with the updated Parse SDK. I removed it from my project, linked an older version of the Parse.framework I had stored and no longer received the errors. Hopefully this is resolved soon.